# Java interesting questions related to bits number generator

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have two questions:

1. I need to generates a random 80-bit distinguisher value in **java**.
2. Need to create a counter in **java** with mentioned property : This counter is 48 bits and is initialized to zero.

How do I do that? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BigInteger class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html and the class SecureRandom: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html